# PHP Create a new variable from birthdate multiple fields

Tags: php, forms, date, post

I am using a PHP `checkdate();` function that will check the date submitted by multiple post fields (ex. `$_POST['month']`, `$_POST['day']`, `$_POST['year']`). The `checkdate()` function returns false even though the fields are selected and the date is a valid date.

I can't figure out why this happens?

EDIT #1: Detailed view of actual code.

Code is submitted by $_POST and entered into an OOP Class "new Register"

```
$register=new register(...., $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'],...);


$this->birthdate=$byear.'-'.$bmonth.'-'.$bday;
$this->b_month=(int)bmonth;
$this->b_day=(int)bday;
$this->b_year=(int)byear;
```

Then the birthdate is checked

```
    public function checkBirthdate(){

        if(checkdate($this->b_month, $this->b_day, $this->b_year)){

            return true;
        } else {

            return false;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I suggest you print variables and see if you get them correctly

Comment: @ibrahim: How do I do that? I'm using a jQuery AJAX to submit the data.

Comment: @KevinKarimu `var_dump($_POST);` and see what's inside. Also, as long as it's user input you need to validate it. I'd cast it to int (`$year = (int)$_POST['year']`).

Comment: The values ​​of the variables must be integers. Also, make sure that the day and month not start with 0, ie, "01" is not a valid value for checkdate() function.

Comment: @ibrahim: I just realized something. Does it matter if the data submitted is using type text or an actual integer?

Comment: not "really". It only depends on the value (php is flexible in regards to text,... but for example "01" is not an integer but "1" would be).

Best would be if you put the values that you have in the $_POST into your post that way you can be helped more effectively.

Comment: @Kevin Thomas is right. For example I can give "12" as a string and it works fine. But if I give "fdg12" it will return error.

Comment: I have updated my post for a detailed view at the problem.

Comment: @KevinKarimu Do you assign `$this->b_month` and so on in constructor of class `register`?

Comment: @PLB: Yes I did. I'm sorry, I forgot to include that in my post. I have edited the post.

Answer (score 1):

Your `register` class needs look like:

```
class register
{
    protected $b_month;
    protected $b_day;
    protected $b_year;

    public function __construct(...., $month, $day, $year, ...)
    {
        $this->b_month = (int)$month;
        $this->b_day = (int)$day;
        $this->b_year = (int)$year;
    }

    public function checkBirthdate(){
        if(checkdate($this->b_month, $this->b_day, $this->b_year)){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}

// usage example
$r = new register(...., $_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year'],...);
echo $r->checkBirthdate() ? 'Valid!' : 'Not Valid!';
```

Based on the code in your question, you create the register object but then assign `b_month`, `b_day`, `b_year` to something else.

Comment: Ok! So I DO need to include the (int) when I do the copy constructor?

Comment: Actually the int is not required for the checkdate call but it's worth doing anyway because it cleans your variables of unwanted characters.

Comment: The problem still persists. I'm trying to figure out what the heck is wrong here.

Comment: The code is updated. I found that the form is submitting the date as it should. However, the dates are being changed to "0" somehow after the new Register object is made and the construct does it's job.

Comment: @KevinKarimu you might have the post names wrong then, double check `$_POST['month']` matches your input name=month etc etc

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like this

```
class Register {
 private $b_year;
 private $b_day;
 private $b_year;

public function __construct( $month,$day,$year )
{
 $this->b_year = $year;
 $this->b_month = $month;
 $this->b_day;
}

public function checkValidDate()
{
  if( checkdate($this->b_month,$this->b_day,$this->b_year) ) return true;
  return false

}

}

if( !isset( $_POST ) ) {  
<form action="" type="POST">
Month: <select name="month">
<option value="1">January</option>
<option value="2">February</option>
so on...so forth..
</select>

Day: <select name="day">
Day<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
so on...so forth..
</select>

Year: <select name="year">
<option value="2012">2012</option>
<option value="2011">2011</option>
so on...so forth..
</select>
<input type="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
} else {
$register=new register($_POST['month'], $_POST['day'], $_POST['year']);
    if( $register->checkValidDate() ) echo "Valid!";
    else echo "Invalid!";
}
```

Comment: The data of $_POST comes from drop down menus where the dates are selected. Could the issue come from there?

Comment: Yes..maybe..try to Did you try echoing those values? if yes, what are the values?

Comment: I ended up with "0" for some strange reason.

Comment: I found that the form is submitting "0" some how. It is somewhere between submitting the form and the copy constructor. All I have in the copy constructor is $this->b_month=$bmonth;

Comment: I updated the code above. Kindly do a print_r( $_POST ) then paste here the output

Comment: Array
(
    [content] => fname=Britney&lname=Spears&email=kspears%40federline.net&sex=F&bmonth=4&bday=4&byear=1969&phone=1-913-999-6831&country=US&alias=Britney+F.+Spears&handle=bspearsfed&password=1234&cpassword=1234&recaptcha_challenge_field=03AHJ_VuujcqyJredkSNIe8vkD1owhAl1srilXIXMV4LCxL9PJqSoXuoyOsAKWR8sWVrKf6T0P2lpc940ZZRXHzOfe3hsnonvrHxTf0xI70VbWmVBynMw4iY_TPXaEXZvflNiGQIxqVDDC6eqlDzdBiTuePr2VkUjFCwNEdfZem0ulpE7F_vgFEg0&recaptcha_response_field=
)

Comment: Looks like its returning a $_GET parameter not a $_POST, did you try echo $_GET['bday'] ? and also make sure your form is type POST

Comment: Ok. It's $POSTing correctly. The problem lies in the value of private member variables $b_month, b_day, b_year. They all have the value of 0 for some reason.

Comment: Everything is type $POST, the form, the jquery ajax, and the variables passed into the new Register object are of type $_POST.

Comment: Sorry forgot to tag you in the comment.